# Publish via a zmq publisher socket, but only for a specific topic

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I am using the zmq node.js module and have publisher/subscriber working. But the publisher publishes messages without a topic right now:

```
    publisher.send(JSON.stringify({some object }));
```

and the subscriber subscribes to all topcis:

subscriber.subscribe(""); //all messages

That works really nicely, but I'd like to restrict the publishing to specific topics. I could not find how to do that in the documentation - can someone tell me how I publish messages for specific topics only?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! Let's say you want to publish some messages with the topic `fahrvergnügen`, and some others with the topic `expeditiously`.

Subscriber one is only interested in topics related to [the joy of driving](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOnne-90CLI):

```
subscriber1.subscribe('fahrvergnügen');
```

Subscriber two is only interested in [appropriate methods to dispose of estranged paramours](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WeparQtwcs):

```
subscriber2.subscribe('expeditiously');
```

Now in your server, instead of sending a string that goes out to everyone, send an array of `frames`, where the first one is your topic and the second (and any subsequent frames) are your message parts:

```
publisher.send(['fahrvergnügen', 'message part one', 'message part two']);
publisher.send(['expeditiously', 'To be efficient and speedy']);
```